# What does IDA mean by this?

Tags: c, java-native-interface, disassembly, decompiling, ida

I have decompiled JNI function code with IDA. An encrypted key is sent to the second argument through the java function, after that something happens to it here and it is used as an HMAC key, but IDA strangely decompiled the code, because of this the algorithm is completely incomprehensible.

```
{
  jbyteArray signature_byteArray; // r5
  JNIEnv env2; // r0
  int data_len2; // r0
  char *data_bytes; // r9
  jbyteArray data_bytes2; // r1
  int data_len; // r10
  int encoded_key_len; // r0
  uint8_t **key; // r4
  uint8_t **key_sha1; // r0
  __int64 v16; // d17
  int signature_hmacResult; // r0
  __int64 v18; // d17
  int v20[2]; // [sp+8h] [bp-F0h] BYREF
  jbyte buffer; // [sp+13h] [bp-E5h] BYREF
  __int64 v22; // [sp+14h] [bp-E4h]
  __int64 v23; // [sp+1Ch] [bp-DCh]
  int v24; // [sp+24h] [bp-D4h]
  char sha1nfo[176]; // [sp+28h] [bp-D0h] BYREF
 
  signature_byteArray = 0;
  if ( data_bytes_argument && encoded_key_bytes )
  {
    env2 = *env;
    v20[0] = thiz;
    data_len2 = (env2->GetArrayLength)(env, data_bytes_argument);
    v20[1] = v20;
    data_bytes = v20 - ((data_len2 + 7) & 0xFFFFFFF8);
    data_bytes2 = data_bytes_argument;
    data_len = data_len2;
    signature_byteArray = 0;
    ((*env)->GetByteArrayRegion)(env, data_bytes2, 0, data_len2, data_bytes);
    encoded_key_len = ((*env)->GetArrayLength)(env, encoded_key_bytes);
    if ( encoded_key_len < 1 || (encoded_key_len & 0xF) != 0 )
    {
      byte_AA20[0] = 0;
      dword_B224 = 71;
    }
    else
    {
      key = (v20 - ((encoded_key_len + 7) & 0xFFFFFFF8));
      signature_byteArray = 0;
      if ( j__a(env, v20[0], &unk_A994) )
      {
        j_sha1_init(sha1nfo);
        j_sha1_write(sha1nfo, key, 20);
        key_sha1 = j_sha1_result(sha1nfo);
        v16 = *(key_sha1 + 1);
        *key = *key_sha1;
        *(key + 1) = v16;
        key[4] = key_sha1[4];
        j_sha1_initHmac(sha1nfo, key, 20);
        j_sha1_write(sha1nfo, data_bytes, data_len);
        buffer = 0x22;
        signature_hmacResult = j_sha1_resultHmac(sha1nfo);
        v18 = *(signature_hmacResult + 8);
        v22 = *signature_hmacResult;
        v23 = v18;
        v24 = *(signature_hmacResult + 16);
        signature_byteArray = ((*env)->NewByteArray)(env, 0x15);
        ((*env)->SetByteArrayRegion)(env, signature_byteArray, 0, 0x15, &buffer);
      }
    }
  }
  return signature_byteArray;
}
```

can you explain what's going on in the lines:

```
key = (v20 - ((encoded_key_len + 7) & 0xFFFFFFF8));

v16 = *(key_sha1 + 1);
*key = *key_sha1;
*(key + 1) = v16;
key[4] = key_sha1[4];
```

Comment: Are you familiar with how C-style structs are laid-out in memory?

Comment: This does not look particularly less comprehensible than any other decompiler output.  It's better than some I've seen, in fact.

Comment: @Dai
no i am not familiar with this

Answer (score 1):

The expression:

```
(encoded_key_len + 7) & 0xFFFFFFF8
```

returns the first value larger than `encoded_key_len` which is multiple of 8 and:

```
key = (v20 - ((encoded_key_len + 7) & 0xFFFFFFF8));
```

practically allocates some memory on stack. It is something like this:

```
unsigned char key[(encoded_key_len + 7) & 0xFFFFFFF8];
```

By the way, when you use IDA, try to rename auto-created argument/variable names to something that is logically correct and makes sense. In this way, you can analyze decompiled code better. For example in the above code, you can change `data_bytes_argument` to `data_arr` which makes much more sense.

Comment: ida automatically converts unsigned char * key to unsigned __int8 * key and this did not affect the code in any way
in the library for use, this variable must be of type uint8_t * key for use in
`void sha1_initHmac (sha1nfo * s, const uint8_t * key, int keyLength);`